# how do i generate a uniqueidentifier

Tags: javascript, sqlite

i develop application mobile where i use framework phonegap, and
i use to insert data into local data base  my question is how do 
to generate a uniqueidentifier for sqlite with javascript?

```
    CREATE TABLE foobar (id uniqueidentifier, foo text, bar text, PRIMARY 
    KEY (id)); 

    insert into foobar values (newid(), "Aaa", "Bbb"); 



    id                                        foo      bar 
    ___________________________________________________________ 

    {00000109-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}    "Aaa"    "Bbb"
```

Comment: What's the deal with that 8-4-4-4-12 GUID format? Seen it a couple of times already, looks pretty arbitrary (edit -> Got that: RFC 4122)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript out to generate UID

Comment: @JonathandeM. big thks, but i'll insert into database, then you think we can not even have the key confusion?

Comment: quasi-impossible, there is one chance on 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456 to create twice the same UID.

Comment: Generating a unique id on the client side and then using it in your database doesn't sound very safe =/

Answer (score 0):

You have differents choices:

1. Take the [compacted version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript) by Broofa
2. Take [this version](http://www.broofa.com/Tools/Math.uuid.js) which add uuid method to Math object. Then just call Math.uuid() to generate a random UUID, also by Broofa.
3. [A complete library](https://github.com/LiosK/UUID.js) for multiple operation on the uuid, for exemple you could use the version 4 (random-numbers-based) as well as the version 1(time-based).

To finish, as said in the comment there are [340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456 possible UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), so don't worry about generating twice the same, you would have more chance trying to win lottery 1 billion times.